# MySQL Limit By Record Type

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to create a comment - reply system. The comments and replies are the same thing and in the same table; only distinguished by the ones that have a `parent_id` field (the ones with a parent are the replies).

The problem is, I want 4 comments and 3 replies, for example, and this is impossible since I can limit only the total amount of rows. Is there a way to accomplish this without having comments and replies in different tables?

The idea is simple:

```
Comment 1
    reply
    reply
    reply

Comment 2
    reply
    reply

Comment 3
    reply
    reply
    reply

Comment 4
    reply
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for nested queries with a loop.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context (e.g. are these numbers fixed for display purposes?  Are the 3 replies per comment and by this do you mean 0 - 3 max replies or are these independent replies for some other purpose?  Is there a working example of what you are looking to do?).  The context will help us to visualise the problem better and will likely determine the best approach to use.  As developerwjk mentioned above you can use nested queries but it may not be efficient or appropriate to do so (depending on what exactly you are looking to achieve and the solution you are building).

Comment: The replies are tied to one comment, the parent. I want a certain number of replies and comments for display purposes and speed.

Answer (score -1):

Create two tables (comments, and comment_replies). One with

> commentId, text

And one with

> commentId, replyId.

Both id's point to a commentId in the comments table. So you have all comments and replies in one table, but connect them through another. You can then easily bet all replies of a comment and limit them to any number.